# I am trying to implement and 'undo' JButton on a simple bank system that will undo the last action performed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have the rest of the code running but I'm not sure what to do in the ActionListener for the Undo Button. I only have this as far as the action listener goes

```
    private class UndoButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
```

I'll post the rest of the GUI class below for reference because this isn't an assignment (it is, just not in a GUI) I appreciate any advice anybody could give me.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;


    public class BankGUI extends JFrame {
private JLabel checking;
private JLabel saving;
private JButton depChecking;
private JButton depSaving;
private JButton witChecking;
private JButton withSaving;
private JButton transferToSaving;
private JButton transferToChecking;
private JButton undo;
private JTextField checkingAmt;
private JTextField savingAmt;
private JTextField depositChk;
private JTextField depositSav;
private JTextField withChk;
private JTextField withSav;
private JTextField transChk;
private JTextField transSav;

public BankGUI() {
    super( "Bank Application" );
    setLayout(new FlowLayout() );

    checkingAmt = new JTextField(10);
    checkingAmt.setEditable(false);
    checkingAmt.setText("500.00");
    add( checkingAmt );

    savingAmt = new JTextField(10);
    savingAmt.setEditable(false);
    savingAmt.setText("0.00");
    add(savingAmt);

    checking = new JLabel( "                  Checking        ");
    add(checking);

    saving = new JLabel( "      Saving              " );
    add(saving);

    depChecking = new JButton( "  Deposit  " );
    add(depChecking);
    depChecking.addActionListener(new DepChkButtonHandler());

    depSaving = new JButton( "  Deposit  " );
    add(depSaving);
    depSaving.addActionListener(new DepSavButtonHandler());

    depositChk = new JTextField(10);
    depositChk.setEditable(true);
    add(depositChk);

    depositSav = new JTextField(10);
    depositSav.setEditable(true);
    add(depositSav);

    witChecking = new JButton( "  Withdraw  " );
    add(witChecking);
    witChecking.addActionListener(new WitChkButtonHandler());

    withSaving = new JButton( "  Withdraw  " );
    add(withSaving);
    withSaving.addActionListener(new WithSavButtonHandler());

    withChk = new JTextField(10);
    withChk.setEditable(true);
    add(withChk);

    withSav = new JTextField(10);
    withSav.setEditable(true);
    add(withSav);

    transferToSaving = new JButton( "  Transfer  " );
    add(transferToSaving);
    transferToSaving.addActionListener(new TranstoSavButtonHandler());

    transferToChecking = new JButton( "  Transfer  " );
    add(transferToChecking);
    transferToChecking.addActionListener(new TranstoChkButtonHandler());

    transSav = new JTextField(10);
    transSav.setEditable(true);
    add(transSav);

    transChk = new JTextField(10);
    transChk.setEditable(true);
    add(transChk);

    undo = new JButton( "  Undo  " );
    add(undo);
}

private class DepChkButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double depAmt = Double.parseDouble(depositChk.getText());
        double chkAmt = Double.parseDouble(checkingAmt.getText());
        String newAmt = deciFormat.format(depAmt + chkAmt);

        checkingAmt.setText(newAmt);

    }

}

private class DepSavButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double depAmt = Double.parseDouble(depositSav.getText());
        double savAmt = Double.parseDouble(savingAmt.getText());
        String newAmt = deciFormat.format(depAmt + savAmt);

        savingAmt.setText(newAmt);

    }

}

private class WitChkButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double witAmt = Double.parseDouble(withChk.getText());
        double chkAmt = Double.parseDouble(checkingAmt.getText());
        String newAmt = deciFormat.format(chkAmt - witAmt);

        checkingAmt.setText(newAmt);

    }

}

private class WithSavButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double witAmt = Double.parseDouble(withSav.getText());
        double savAmt = Double.parseDouble(savingAmt.getText());
        String newAmt = deciFormat.format(savAmt - witAmt);

        savingAmt.setText(newAmt);

    }

}

private class TranstoSavButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double transAmt = Double.parseDouble(transSav.getText());
        double savAmt = Double.parseDouble(savingAmt.getText());
        double chkAmt = Double.parseDouble(checkingAmt.getText());
        String newAmt1 = deciFormat.format(savAmt + transAmt);
        String newAmt2 = deciFormat.format(chkAmt - transAmt);
        savingAmt.setText(newAmt1);
        checkingAmt.setText(newAmt2);

    }

}

private class TranstoChkButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        double transAmt = Double.parseDouble(transChk.getText());
        double savAmt = Double.parseDouble(savingAmt.getText());
        double chkAmt = Double.parseDouble(checkingAmt.getText());
        String newAmt1 = deciFormat.format(savAmt - transAmt);
        String newAmt2 = deciFormat.format(chkAmt + transAmt);
        savingAmt.setText(newAmt1);
        checkingAmt.setText(newAmt2);

    }

}

private class UndoButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide how deep your undo will go. Can the user undo the last 10 operations, or just the most recent? This decision will determine whether you store the last operation as a simple field, or as some sort of `List` of transactions (some sort of `Queue` might do, as well).

You should also normalize your transactions into some sort of model that can reflect the details of every kind of transaction supported by your application. In other words, you need a `Transaction` object, with fields like `amount`, `sourceAcct`, `destinationAcct` or however you want to do it. The point is that this Transaction object needs to be able to represent everything a user might want to do (or undo) in your program.

This Transaction object will be used to do the normal bookkeeping (adding or removing money from an account), but after the balance has been adjusted, you save the Transaction to your `lastTransaction` field or your `transActions` List.

Create a method called `undo` and put it in your undo handler. When the user clicks the undo button, your `undo` method just looks at the most recent transaction and reverses it. For example, if the transaction was a deposit of $100 to checking, when you undo it, instead of adding $100 to checking, you subtract $100 from checking. If you're working with a list of transactions, make sure you remove the Transaction after you've reversed it.

Comment: Just the last operation will work for now, that's a great idea! I was getting serious mental block from working on different projects all day but I think you've given me a fresh Idea. I appreciate it.